# How to force apache point to latest php version installed?

Tags: php, apache, redhat

I have a problem in my red hat server. 
previously it was installed with php 5.2.. 
Then i upgrade to php 5.3.8 with reimi repo.. 
if use phpinfo() it display 5.3.8 version.
but from command line

> php -v 
>   PHP 5.2.17 (cli) (built: Nov 18 2011 18:55:39) Copyright (c)
>   1997-2010 The PHP Group Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010
>   Zend Technologies
>       with Xdebug v2.1.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2011, by Derick Rethans

this is installed packages:

> rpm -qa | grep php 
>   php-mysql-5.3.8-5.el5.remi.1
>   php-pdo-5.3.8-5.el5.remi.1 php-5.3.8-5.el5.remi.1
>   php-mbstring-5.3.8-5.el5.remi.1 php-pear-1.9.4-3.el5.remi
>   php-cli-5.3.8-5.el5.remi.1 php-xml-5.3.8-5.el5.remi.1
>   php-common-5.3.8-5.el5.remi.1 php-gd-5.3.8-5.el5.remi.1

can i force apache to point to php 5.3 instead of 5.2 when command 'php -v'

Comment: Apache has nothing to do with the CLI version. Update the `php-cli` package, or whatever it's called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CLI PHP has nothing to do with Web-Server. If you see 5.3.8 in your phpinfo() output, then you got what you want. You might upgrade your PHP CLI.

Comment: how to upgrade the php-cli..? need to remove the current installed and  install latest version?